# Adding Notes to MS Word Doc

Tags: microsoft-word

I am want a Word Template that has various sections to fill things out.  I would also like to add notes to each section. This would be a bit like powerpoint notes.  You only see them if you have a certain view enabled.  It must be easy for the user to enable or disable them.  I know you can add tooltips to Headers and Bookmarks but the information I am adding is more like paragraphs not simple one liners.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: Write more into your note than a one liner? It's not really clear what the current tools don't allow you to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a style for these notes (or repurpose an existing style that you won't use for anything else), and, in the Font properties, select the **Hidden** check box. Users will then see the text if the **Show/Hide ¶** option is selected in the **Paragraph** group on the **Home** tab (or if the **Hidden text** check box is selected under **Always show these formatting marks on the screen** on the **Display** tab in Word Options); otherwise, the text will be hidden. It will also be hidden when the doc is printed, converted to a PDF, or read in Word's **Read Mode** view.